# Typewriter effect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a typewriting effect in a React component. I pass in an array of strings and try to render them character by character after some interval (using setTimeout). Here is my code for that

```
  state = {
    typeColor: {
      color: "blue"
    },
    typed: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.typewriter.map(string => {
      console.log("1", string);
      return this.stringChecker(string);
    });
  }

  typeWriter(string) {
    if (string.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("3", string);
    this.setState((state, props) => ({ typed: state.typed.concat(string[0]) }));
    console.log(this.state.typed);

    setTimeout(() => this.typeWriter(string.slice(1)), 120);
  }
  stringChecker(string) {
    console.log("2", string);
    if (string === "Qurram") {
      this.setState({ typeColor: { color: "blue" } });
    } else {
      this.setState({ typeColor: { color: "pink" } });
    }
    this.typeWriter(string);
  }

  render() {
    return <div style={this.state.typeColor}>{this.state.typed}</div>;
  }
}
```

Now I was expecting the execution flow of this to go like this: first element of string array is 'selected' in the map function -> i call stringchecker for that first element -> i call typewriter for that first element, and iterate over the characters. then i go back to the map function and do the same for next. It seems the flow is not like this at all,instead it alternates between the two strings for each character slice. I'd really appreciate if someone could explain that to me. Thank you very much

Sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-dust-18nq5

Comment: Can you so a stackblitz example for the question.

Comment: @AkhilAravind I've added sandbox link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typing logic is good, however, note that setTimeout is async, so it doesn't wait for the whole word to be typed before switching to the next one. The solution is to make the whole typing flow async, so you don't switch to the next word before the previous one has been typed.

Here's the sandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-greider-824nd

The main change is this one:

```
if (string.length === 0) {
  words = words.slice(1);
  words[0] && this.typeWord(words[0], words);
}
```

Check if we finished typing a word, then slice it, to get the next word. If we still have words we call `typeWord` with the word that should be typed and the array of words that should be typed next. If there are no words left, we exit typing.

Answer (score 4):

You may simply employ `useEffect()` hook that will increase visible part of the text (stored within component's state) after each re-render (with random delay) until the entire text is out.

Live-demo of this concept you may find below:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM
      

const srcString = `That's the text I'm going to print out`

const Typewriter = ({srcString}) => {

  const [{content,carriage}, setContent] = useState({content:'',carriage:0})
       
  useEffect(() => {
    if(carriage == srcString.length) return
    const delay = setTimeout(() => {
      setContent({content:content+srcString[carriage], carriage: carriage+1})
      clearTimeout(delay)
    }, 0|(Math.random()*200+50))
  }, [content])
  
  return <span>{content}<span className="cursor">|</span></span>
  
}

render (
  <Typewriter {...{srcString}} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.cursor{animation:1s blink step-end infinite}@keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}@-moz-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}@-webkit-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}@-ms-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}@-o-keyframes blink{from,to{color:transparent}50%{color:#000}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, `setTimeout()` can be tricky when working with tasks that need to execute synchronously (like a typing effect).

Here's another approach using `async/await`. I made the `typeWriter` method async, and so it'll only return once all of the characters in the string have been typed. After that, the NEXT string will be allowed to type. For this to work, `stringChecker` also needs to be async. Check it out and let me know if anything's confusing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-davinci-d5bk5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Also... if you just want to get it up and running, I made a TypeIt, a JS typing library, and there's also a React component version of it. If it's useful, check it out:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit-react

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, a small custom hook I wrote

```
export const useTypeWriter = (content = '') => {
    const [prevContent, setPrevContent] = useState(content);
    const [animatedContent, setAnimatedContent] = useState('');
    const hasContentChanged = prevContent === content;

    const generateContent = () => {
        setAnimatedContent((prevAnimatedContent) => {
            const charCount = prevAnimatedContent.length;
            if (prevAnimatedContent.length + 1 !== content.length) setTimeout(generateContent, 90);

            return prevAnimatedContent + content[charCount];
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!hasContentChanged) return;

        setPrevContent(content);
        generateContent(content);
    }, [hasContentChanged]);

    return animatedContent;
};
```